# How to setup CORS properly in Go?

Tags: docker, go, cors

```
ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
CACHE_SIZE_MB=32
CORS_ENABLED=true
CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS=
CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS=
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=
CORS_DEBUG=true
HOST_ONLY_DOMAINS=*
HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=5s
HTTP_MAX_AGE_DURATION=720h
HTTP_USER_AGENT=''
POPULAR_SITES=bing.com,github.com,instagram.com,reddit.com
PORT=8080
SERVER_MODE=redirect
```

I have this docker_run file. From the Go server how to properly set up this file?

I have an example.com where the server hosted and I am trying to use this API to my example1.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this docker_run file. From the Go server how to properly set up this file?

This file has nothing to do with Go. I guess it was supposed to be read by the application and applied there.

If you have an instance of `http.HandlerFunc` you can warp it into a new function call in the following way:

```
func setCors(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "your origin value...")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "your methods...")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "your headers...")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "your age...")
        // other settings
        h(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro my question is closed..But you know what you saved my day..I feel so much happy after solving this problem. I am trying the whole day for this solution..I do not know how to thank you.

Comment: @sanketkheni I am glad it helped